# Pulsate from different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pulsate from white to another color but i'm not sure how to add color to this code

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
$("#white36").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3000 }, 500);
});




  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a white element and you want to pulsate to another color (say blue), just put a blue element behind the white one. The white one will fade away and the blue will show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQeury.Color [plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) . With this plugin you can do this:

With this plugin you can use something that:

```
  jQuery("#block").animate({
      backgroundColor: jQuery.Color({ saturation: 0 })
  }, 1500 );
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FbTT/)